# Problem in connecting Broadband ADSL modem in Centos 5.5?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, centos-5

How to connect the BSNL(India) Broadband Adsl modem in Centos 5.5?
I have tried with wvdial,pppoe,adsl-setup etc, but nothing works for me. Is there any other software available for download?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration mainly depends on your modem configuration. You need to use pppoe, if your modem is in bridge mode or use dhcp, if your modem is in lan mode with dhcp server on. I guess the link http://nileshbansal.blogspot.com/2006/12/bsnl-broadband-using-linux.html can help u, if you are going to use pppoe.